# Laravel - 3 Models with many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 3 tables/models and would like to gather output in a one->toMany->toMany. I want to get data from each of the 3 tables in the output. I've tried the hasManyThrough, but that gives me the first and last table relationship. I want the middle (through) table to also be outputted.

Models:

```
student
 - id
 - name

course
 - id
 - student_id
 - name

level
 - id
 - course_id
 - level
```

I want the output to be in one array/multidimensional array that would look like the following:

```
student1 -> english -> 101
         -> history -> 104
                    -> 105

student2 -> english -> 201
                    -> 203
         -> history -> 202
         -> math -> 101

student3 -> english -> 302
         -> math -> 200
                 -> 201
         -> science -> 102
```

I could then foreach through the array and dump it out appropriately like above. The hasManyThrough doesn't appear to get me the courses, just the student1 -> 201 output.

The hasManyThrough looks like this:

```
public function courselevels()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Level',
                                     'App\Models\Course',
                                     'student_id',
                                     'course_id',
                                     'id',
                                     'id');

    }
```

I've also tried a plain query builder like so:

```
$userSoftware = DB::table('student')
    ->join('course', 'course.student_id', '=', 'student.id')
    ->join('level', 'level.course_id', '=', 'course.id')
    ->select('course.display_name', 'level.*')
    ->get();
```

This works to a point, but i have duplicates for each array element returned like so:

```
student1 -> english -> 101
student1 -> history -> 104
student1 -> history -> 105

student2 -> english -> 201
student2 -> english -> 203
student2 -> history -> 202
student2 -> math -> 101

student3 -> english -> 302
student3 -> math -> 200
student3 -> math -> 201
student3 -> science -> 102
```

I'm fine with either Eloquent models and a hasThroughMany setup, or using a normal query builder on the controller.

Comment: Set a one to many relationship between student and courses and a many-to-many relationship between courses and levels. Then you can easily load the data you want using eager loading with the relationships

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Student model, you should have a courses() relationship and in Course model, you should have a levels() relationship.
Then when you want all data you query with `with('courses.levels')`.

```
// student model
public function courses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
}

// Course model
public function levels()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Level::class);
}

$student = Student::with('courses.levels')->get();

// loop through courses
foreach ( $student->courses as $course ) {
  
  // $course->levels
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the eloquent relationships like that and chaining them. This worked perfectly.